# How do I connect multiple (7 or 8) toggle switches to a raspberry pi?

Tags: display, breadboard, switches

I haven't bought any of the components I'd need yet, partially because I'm not sure I'm on the right track.

I want to connect 7 or 8 toggle switches (SPST) to a raspberry pi, which then read in would give 128 or 256 different combinations.

Based on the combination, I would like to display a specific photo (from micro SD card/ USB in rasbperry pi) on an hdmi connected screen.

Here are my questions:

- Can I do this on a Raspberry Pi 3 Model A+?
- Is there anything specific I need to look for when buying switches? Are all of them the same?
- How do I connect the switches so their state could be read individually in order to produce the 128/ 256 different combinations? Do I need a breadboard? Can I connect them through wiring only?
- What tools do I need?

I apologize for the amount of questions in here. Please let me know if I can provide any additional details.

Thank you!

Comment: How do you propose to connect 7 or 8 switches to get 128 or 258 combinations from the switches. How many buttons are you going to press. Are they to be pressed one at a time or all at once? Once you get this figured out everything else if feasible. You can put the switches together in any way you want. Your processor should be more than adequate. I would suggest you get one of the inexpensive 24 MHz logic analyzers a multimeter and a scope if you can afford one. Soldering etc depends on your assembly method.

Comment: Please start with a single switch & do your homework. There are many examples online for the cost of an Internet search in your favorite search engine. Choose a GPIO library, learn how to set the pullups in code. Connect a toggle to a GPIO pin & write a program to read the state of tha GPIO pin. One.step.at.a.time is how to do this.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.